# App crashes when api call returns zero results

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit

so, I've been writing a cocktails app, using the https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api.php. One of its functions is to search for cocktails based on ingredient, return a list of those and display them using a recyclerView. When I input an ingredient that does not exist (for example Vwdka), the app crashes

Here is my api's interface:

```
interface CocktailApi {

//@Query("i") i: String = "Empty"
@GET("/api/json/v1/1/filter.php?")
suspend fun getCocktailsByBase(
    @Query("i") i: String = "Empty"
): Response<CocktailsByBaseDto>?

@GET("/api/json/v1/1/lookup.php?")
suspend fun getCocktailDetailsById(
    @Query("i") i: String
): Response<CocktailDetailsByIdDto>?
```

Here is the related fragment

```
class CocktailsMainScreenFinderFragment: Fragment(R.layout.cocktails_main_screen_finder_fragment) {

private var _binding: CocktailsMainScreenFinderFragmentBinding? = null
private val binding get() = _binding!!
private lateinit var viewModel: CocktailsViewModel
private lateinit var cocktailsAdapter: CocktailsAdapter
private val TAG = "CocktailsMainScreenFinderFragment"

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    _binding = CocktailsMainScreenFinderFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    viewModel = (activity as MainActivity).viewModel
    setupRecyclerView()

    var job: Job? = null
    binding.svCocktailsMainSearch.addTextChangedListener {
        job?.cancel()
        job = MainScope().launch {
            delay(500L)
            it?.let {
                if (binding.svCocktailsMainSearch.toString().isNotEmpty()) {
                    viewModel.getCocktails(binding.svCocktailsMainSearch.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    viewModel.cocktails.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        when(response) {
            is Resource.Success -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.data?.let { cocktailsResponse ->
                    cocktailsAdapter.differ.submitList(cocktailsResponse.drinks)
                }
            }
            is Resource.Error -> {
                hideProgressBar()
                response.message?.let { message ->
                    Log.e("MainScreenFragment", "An error occurred: $message")
                }
                binding.tvCocktailsMainNoCocktailsFound.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.ivCocktailsMainNoCocktailsFound.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            is Resource.Loading -> {
                showProgressBar()
            }
        }
    })
}

private fun setupRecyclerView() {
    cocktailsAdapter = CocktailsAdapter()
    binding.rvCocktailsMain.apply {
        adapter = cocktailsAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
    }
}

private fun hideProgressBar() {
    binding.pbCocktailsMain.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
}

private fun showProgressBar() {
    binding.pbCocktailsMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

}

And here is the adapter:

```
class CocktailsAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<CocktailsAdapter.CocktailsViewHolder>() {

inner class CocktailsViewHolder(val binding: ItemCocktailPreviewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root)


private val differCallback = object  : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Drink>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame( oldItem: Drink, newItem: Drink): Boolean {
        return oldItem.idDrink == newItem.idDrink
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Drink, newItem: Drink): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CocktailsViewHolder {
    return CocktailsViewHolder(
        ItemCocktailPreviewBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
    )
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CocktailsViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val binding = holder.binding
    val cocktail = differ.currentList[position]

    holder.itemView.apply {
        Glide.with(this).load(cocktail.strDrinkThumb).into(binding.imgCocktailsMainRecyclerViewImage)
        binding.tvCocktailsMainRecyclerViewTitle.text = cocktail.strDrink
        setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener?.let { it }
        }
    }
}


override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.count()
}

private var onItemClickListener: ((CocktailsByBaseDto) -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (CocktailsByBaseDto) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error of the crash

Comment: java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: "When I input an ingredient that does not exist (for example Vwdka), the app crashes" -- talk to whoever maintains that server and make sure that they send back valid JSON for that case. Beyond that, your [mcve] includes neither a stack trace nor the code that is using `CocktailApi`.